# no valid sudoers sources found after running sudo chmod -R 777 /etc on AWS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, sudoers

As I said, I did a stupid thing on Amazon Web Services.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /etc`
```

which gives this when using sudo:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Now I found this on the web: https://askubuntu.com/a/162889/421314

```
pkexec chmod -R 755 /etc`
```

but it wants my super user password or something. My Ubuntu user password is not working...

```
pkexec chmod -R 755 /etc
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/chmod' as the super user
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
This incident has been reported.
```

What to do?

Comment: Are you able to run pkexec after issuing the command `sudo su -`

Comment: Hi @RenjuChandranchingath no, sudo is completely destroyed. Thx %)p! See updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Just to recapitulate, what I did to recover:

--  basically here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=581788.

**Stop the instance in question.**

Do not terminate it. Then it is gone.

**Take a snapshot of the root volume (For backup just in case).**

**Detach the root volume from the instance.(Take note of the mount point e.g /dev/sda1)**

**Launch a new temporary instance or use an existing Linux instance.**

You have no influence on in which availibility zone it is created. Although this is important later.

**Attach and mount the root volume as a secondary volume to the temp instance.**

Since you can only do this in the same availability zone, you might have to generate a new volume from the snapshot, in the availability zone the temp instance is.

**Fix the sudoers file**

This is the most shortened version of an advice ever.

You have to mount the volume, in order to access it.

First you have to find out the name, the system gave to the volume by `lsblk`. The name should be corresponding to the mount point previously in AWS, but changed to xvda1. E.g. sda1 to xvda1.

Then

```
sudo mkdir /media/new/_yourName_
sudo mount /dev/_yourFoundPartition_ /media/new/_yourName_
```

Now it should be in `/Volumes`.

Fix the sudoers file or the write permissions.

**Stop the temp instance**

Make a snapshot of the fixed volume.

**Detach the volume.**

```
umount -d /dev/_yourFoundPartition_
```

**Attach the volume back to the stopped volume with the mount point noted earlier.**

As I said earlier, you have trouble most likely with the availability zone. You might have to take the snapshot of the fixed volume, and generate a new volume in the old instance’s availability zone.

**Start the instance.**

In the end I could not SSH into the machine anymore. So I ended up changing the DNS to the temp instance. And attaching the volume as main volume.

But remember, that you have trouble with different availability zones, mounting and unmounting the volume, getting it all back.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mount-drive-from-command-line-ubuntu-linux/
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1775679
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=544552

It is not a joyride as written in the short article.

Edit: Found a nice video of AWSers themselves https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P29ZHu_feU.
:)

Good luck!!

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: @DragonLord Ok, I will do. But tomorrow. 3AM here %)P. I hope I will not have forgotten everything after waking up! (Nightmare.)

Comment: @DragonLord Done. Is it all right? Can you have a glance over it, at least the mounting part? Love